# How to handle routes in react based on dynamic roles and permission received form back end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

we have a react.js application that uses react-router v.6 we receive roles and permissions from back-end when user logs in,we want to toggle menu items and filter routes  based on role/permission.

how should front-end and back-end communicate about access to route and menu items?
my solution for private routes so far:

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { userInfoStore } from './auth/login/user-store';

export function PrivateRoute({ children, roles }) {
  const info = userInfoStore((state) => state.info);

  if (!info.role) {
    return <Navigate to="/auth/login" />;
  }
  if (info.role && roles.indexOf(info.role) === -1) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }
  return children;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a reasonable approach. Are there any specific issues you have? Is something not working as expected? What are you *really* asking for?

Comment: I can manage private routes in front by this approach,I can receive identifier from back-end and generate routes. I wonder if there is a better solution to keep front-end and back-end on the same page.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "keep front-end and back-end on the same page." Why would they be on different pages? Why would the backend be on a page?

Comment: I ended up using [this repository](https://github.com/umair-khanzada/role-based-access-control).it helped me to figure out the solution.